# Tooltip-like little floating window with Gtk (Sharp)

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I'm creating a widget to plot light spectrum distributions and I want to show a little tooltip-like floating window next to the mouse pointer showing the wavelength and the power associated to that wavelength (the wavelength associated with the x-position of the mouse pointer).

Right Now I can show a typical tooltip, but with many shortcomings. The tooltip only appears when I keep the pointer motionless a few seconds, and appears at the bottom of the plotter widget, not near the mouse pointer.

I'm doing this with GTK# 2.12 , so GTK3 solutions may not work.

Thanks for your attention :) .

Comment: What kind of window do you need? [Something like this (OS X)](http://media.tumblr.com/bb59b3c3066ca01074c4c5458d8f57d6/tumblr_inline_mud7ufhJ4Q1qzs6su.png) [or this (GTK+ 3.12)](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iZvrrcdQQjY/U5oL6xrJaPI/AAAAAAAAFoE/gOgbtlMhJ1Y/s1600/user-location-marker-new.png)?

Comment: Something like the second one, but with the triangle at the left side of the window box instead of being at the bottom side of the box.